# How to set up dependency injection in Ninject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, akka.net

I am trying to set up Dependency Injection with Akka .NET. Following a Pluralsight course on the subject, I came up with the following adaptation:

```
        var container = new StandardKernel();
        container.Bind<ITimeService>().To<LocalTimeService>();
        container.Bind<TimeLordActor>().ToSelf();

        using (var actorSystem = ActorSystem.Create("MyActorSystem"))
        {
            var resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container, actorSystem);

            var actor = actorSystem.ActorOf(Props.Create<TimeLordActor>(),
                "TimeLordActor");
            actor.Tell("Give me the time!");

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

TimeLordActor's constructor expects a parameter of type `ITimeService`.

However, I get the following error when running:

`[ERROR][7/10/2016 5:39:42 PM][Thread 0012][akka://MyActorSystem/user/TimeLordActor] Error while creating actor instance of type AkkaNetDiExperimental.TimeLordActor with 0 args: ()
Cause: [akka://MyActorSystem/user/TimeLordActor#1586418697]: Akka.Actor.ActorInitializationException: Exception during creation ---> System.TypeLoadException: Error while creating actor instance of type AkkaNetDiExperimental.TimeLordActor with 0 args: () ---> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'AkkaNetDiExperimental.TimeLordActor' not found.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Akka.Actor.Props.ActivatorProducer.Produce()
   at Akka.Actor.Props.NewActor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Actor.Props.NewActor()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.CreateNewActorInstance()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.<>c__DisplayClass118_0.<NewActor>b__0()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.UseThreadContext(Action action)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.NewActor()
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Create(Exception failure)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Create(Exception failure)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.SysMsgInvokeAll(EarliestFirstSystemMessageList messages, Int32 currentState)`

The official documentation on [Akka .NET Dependency Injection](http://getakka.net/docs/Dependency%20injection) suggests that you should use a DI() extension method on the ActorSystem instance when creating actors directly:

```
// Create the Props using the DI extension on your ActorSystem instance
var worker1Ref = system.ActorOf(system.DI().Props<TypedWorker>(), "Worker1");
var worker2Ref = system.ActorOf(system.DI().Props<TypedWorker>(), "Worker2");
```

However, I have been unable to find even this extension method on the actor system.

Can someone please explain how to create a simple actor using dependency injection from the actor system itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. You have to use the `DI()` extension method as suggested by the docs. This is in the `Akka.DI.Core` namespace.

```
using Akka.DI.Core;
```

Then remember to update the actor creation to reflect the method used by the docs:

```
var actor = actorSystem.ActorOf(actorSystem.DI().Props<TimeLordActor>(),
                "TimeLordActor");
```